# Can "darken" be an adjective?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

The movie description of [*Who Framed Roger Rabbit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Framed_Roger_Rabbit) has a line:

> Keeping an eye over his shoulder, Eddie heads down some **darken stairs**.

None of the dictionaries I consulted list **darken** as an adjective. *"Darkened stairs"* doesn't sound right either, and the audio doesn't sound like it. So is "darken" used as an adjective? I am putting the [audio clip here](https://clyp.it/dn3jf023) for reference, uploaded to a Clyp, an audio sharing site.

Comment: It's probably a typo.  *Darkened* stairs is correct, and means "stairs that have become dark".  I definitely hear "darkened" when I listen to the audio.

Comment: /nds/ -- A /d/ in that position is quite difficult to pronounce.  In the absence of unnatural pauses, the /n/ makes an alveolar stop impossible and the /s/ both suppresses the voiced phonation and masks the plosive release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's definitely saying "darkened." He says the "-ed" very quickly, but it's there.

**Darkened** is the past participle of "to darken" and is the correct way to turn the verb "to darken" into an adjective in this case.

You can use *darkened* to describe any number of things that are temporarily dark:

> He started walking down the darkened alleyway.
>
> He stared into the darkened closet, making sure there were no monsters.

Comment: Could enrich this answer with some typical collocations of **darkened**? It is not a word I see very often.

Comment: +1   *His mood had been darkened by the news. He left the meeting with a darkened mood.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Very good point! Darkened can be used metaphorically as well.

Answer (score -2):

Well I also heard it as "darken".. But I'm getting the idea that darken is an adjective because you can compare as:        1) darken stairs (2) woollen sweaters...   and you see that in (1) we see that stairs that are dark (so darken is adjective)  and in (2) sweaters that are made of wooll (so woollen is adjective) ... Someone correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: This seems to me a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @StoneyB: Looks like it's trying to argue for the affirmative, that "darken" is an adjective. So an answer, just a wrong one.

Comment: I'll leave it to the dictionaries at Wordnik to correct you: [_darken_](http://wordnik.com/words/darken) is an verb; [_darkened_](http://wordnik.com/words/darkened) is an adjective.

Comment: I tried to give the answer to the best of my knowledge and was willing to be stand corrected if I were wrong, so guys why have you gone so serious?